# Can I restrict who accesses my Azure website to people in the US?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, ip-address, subnet, azureportal

I want to limit the people who can see and visit my website to only those in the US! I know I can restrict IP addresses to only those I give in my web.config file. Is there some subnet mask or something I can use below to define all US ip addresses or is there some Azure settings I can configure in the Azure portal?

ex.

```html
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false" denyAction="NotFound">
      <add allowed="true" ipAddress="24.130.112.11" subnetMask="255.255.0.0" />
      <add allowed="true" ipAddress="73.92.189.234" subnetMask="255.255.0.0" />
    </ipSecurity>
  </security>
```

Comment: I am not aware of method on limiting traffic to azure website based on region. However, if you have Azure CDN enabled then you can use  geo-filtering feature in order to configure the service to allow or block access to directory path by country. Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-restrict-access-by-country#considerations

Comment: what's Azure CDN?

Comment: and can I just give it a one line configuration that says block all except US?

Comment: The Microsoft Azure Content Delivery Network (CDN) offers developers a global solution for delivering high-bandwidth content that is hosted in Azure or any other location. Using the CDN, you can cache publicly available objects loaded from Azure blob storage, a web application, virtual machine, application folder, or other HTTP/HTTPS location. The CDN cache can be held at strategic locations to provide maximum bandwidth for delivering content to users. The CDN is typically used for delivering static content such as images, style sheets, documents, files, client-side scripts, and HTML pages.

Comment: The major advantages of using the CDN are lower latency and faster delivery of content to users irrespective of their geographical location in relation to the datacenter where the application is hosted.

However, check this out to see if CND really fits your scenerio - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/cdn#how-and-why-a-cdn-is-used

Comment: You can apply geo-filtering for all your files with "/" or selected folders by specifying directory paths e.g. "/pictures/".

Comment: ok, so I'm a little confused. Lets say I set up CDN in my account for my website. If I understand what you are saying correctly, only CDN content gets geo located. So if someone is accessing my site and the CDN hasn't cached everything the user needs (so it takes the user to the full site on Azure) then what you are suggesting won't work! Is that correct??

Comment: because it only limits the CDN stuff right?

Comment: maybe my approach isn't the correct one for what I want to do! When I first roll out my site I want to limit it to a specific region (ex. San Francisco or California). It only seems like other sites have done this, I have no experience with this personally, but it seems like that is how it's done in other cases. Am I wrong here? When you publish a site is it live all over the world, no restrictions other then what the specific country allows/disallows? I know the answer is yes, I was hoping for clarification if I could restrict visibility to just the US. Until I can add more languages, etc etc

Answer (score 1):

There is no Azure setting you can configure in the Azure portal to restrict access based on IP address from any region.

I suggest you could use some nuget package such as [MaxMind.GeoIP2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MaxMind.GeoIP2/) which can provide **GeoIP lookup** functionality to get the location information such as country and city based on the client IP address.

This way would be better than having to find out and whitelist all the IP addresses range and subnet masks for U.S.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that is the only way to restrict IP addressees in Azure. You can also use [IP Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions) menu in Azure app services to add or remove restrictions.

However, I would argue that the approach to limiting users who can access your site by region (IP address) is not the correct solution. It seems like an unnecessary complication that can run into both technical and logical issues. Would you want someone who works in San Francisco but works outside of the city to only be able to access your site when they are in the office?

I think there are a handful of more appropriate and easier to manage solutions such as:

- Prompting the user (if they have never visited your site before) with a message saying the site is in test/alpha/beta and is only intended for X users (English speaking, metropolitan workers, etc.)
- Ask for information on login that matches your description (language, region, location, etc.) and either redirect them to the correct location or have them gracefully leave the site
- Distribute beta keys to anyone you want to access your site. You can be very specific about who you invite especially if you have a certain demographic in mind, which may prove more valuable than simply having a very large pool of users.

Comment: ok thanks for the feedback and help. if you have any other ideas please let me know. thanks!