# Azure - Allow access to a website deployed on Azure App Service only for a single country

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have website deployed on Azure App Service and I want to restrict access to my website from any other country accessing it but only a specific country can access that website.
Is there any way where I can restrict/allow at the infrastructure level inside Azure?

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I have used Azure Frontdoor with WAF and applied rule on WAF where you can apply geolocation rules. This is the only solution I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Answer is: **Azure Front Door** with **Front Door WAF policy**

After going through with different Microsoft documentation I finally implemented the solution with `Azure Front Door` where you can set `Frontend hosts` and `Backend pools` with forwarding/redirecting. And in `Frontend hosts`, you can select `WAF policy`.

In the backend pool, you can select any application e.g. `App Service` or any `IP` where your app is deployed.

In `WAF policy` there are multiple options to restrict your traffic and one of them is `geolocation restriction`.

Just apply geolocation restriction according to your desired country and it will work like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Even though AppService does not provide, Yes this can be done with Azure CDN provider does via the Geo Level Filtering. More details can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-restrict-access-by-country).

Comment: I have gone through that article but I don't have to restrict CDN I need to implement the same in AppService.

Comment: There is no way then. May be you could build another empty app and redirect to that using traffic manager

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way where I can restrict/allow at the infrastructure level inside Azure?

Agree with Sajeetharan. It seems Azure Web App could not restrict the access just by country **directly**. You can have a try with Azure CDN, it can restrict the access by **country**.

But, as the comment you said, you do not have to restrict CDN, in this case, you can consider to restrict **IP addressees** in Azure. You can also use IP Restrictions menu in Azure app services to add restrictions:

You can check the document [Azure App Service Access Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions) for some more details.

Besides, you can try to use `web.config` or use IP restrictions feature of the webapp:

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48590149/can-i-restrict-who-accesses-my-azure-website-to-people-in-the-us) for some more info.

Hope this helps.